# PHP, как разделить массив след. образом?

Tags: php

Добрый день есть массив из N элементов. Как получить в две переменные. В первую массив из первых двух элементов, а в другом массиве остальные элементы. array_chunk лишь разбивает на одинаковое количество. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$two = array_splice($arr, 0, 2);
var_dump($two); // ['a', 'b']
var_dump($arr); // ['c', 'd', 'e']
```